# Why does my external hard disk (SATA) not spin down when idle on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive

I had an Ubuntu server using 18.04 LTS and this had one external hard-drive (not an SSD) connected to it via USB, and it would always spin down after some time as expected. I never configured or enabled anything to achieve that. The default behavior was just fine.

Now I have connected the same external disk to my new Ubuntu 22.04 LTS server and it does not spin down, even when idle for hours. It stays constantly spinning.

Do I need to configure something to make it spin down after some idle time? Or is something touching the disk too often? How can I find out what touches it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I first installed `hd-idle` and I was able to manually spin down the disk immediately using `hd-idle -a sdb -t`.

After some time I looked at the hd-idle log file and at syslog and it occurred to me that `smartd` printed an entry roughly every 30 minutes into syslog (but not for every 30 minute slot).

To disable permanently monitoring my hard-drives I edited `/etc/smartd.conf` and commented out the line which starts with `DEVICESCAN` and then I restarted smartd using `/etc/init.d/smartmontools restart` to reload the configuration.

Since then the external hard-disk spins down as expected (after about 30 minutes).

I remember I installed `smartmontools` in order to determine the health of the SSD storage devices. This probably automatically starts the `smartd` server which monitors all devices, and apparently touching the disk to retrieve the SMART information prevents the disk from spinning down on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. (This is not the case on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS so this is a regression.)

Comment: _smartctl_ can check whether the device is spun down first. Maybe _smartd_ has a similar option.

Comment: The line inside smartd.conf already has `-n standby` directive, which according to `man smartd.conf` means "check the device unless it is in SLEEP or STANDBY mode", and it seems to be working fine. `smartd` waking the disk isn't the problem, but rather the fact that it prevents the disk from going to sleep

Comment: @Infensus: I think your analysis is sport-on. The disk is touched every 30 minutes and so never goes to sleep and so the "do not touch sleeping disks" mechanism does not work. This may be a tight race as the sleep and the touch intervals are both 30 minutes so if the disk manages to go to sleep one second before it would be scanned the problem would not occur.